# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gamelib'

Tags: python

My code is throwing this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gamelib'
and I am not sure why.

I have tried pip installing gamelib but it comes up with this:

ERROR:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gamelib (from versions: none)
>
> No matching distribution found for gamelib

Here is my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

path = 'training_data'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    data = np.load(f'{path}/{file}')
    break

print(data[0])
```

To my understanding, this should print the file but this is not the case

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting `ERROR: No matching distribution found for gamelib`
simply means that you don't have a compatible python version to run `gamelib`. Go to the pip page and check the compatible python versions an then download them.

Comment: The "(from versions: none)" part means that pip found *no* versions of `gamelib`, compatible or not, because there is no `gamelib` package on PyPI at all.